# Slow performance of ZipFile Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip, system.io.compression

I'm writing a code to compress/zip folders and files in C#, and for this purpose, I am using ZipFile method from System.IO.Compression.
Now if I create a zip file using Winrar (fastest mode), it takes considerably less time to zip the folder and the zip file it creates has a reduced size than the zip file created with my program.
Is there a way i can increase performance of my program?

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(path, fileName, CompressionLevel.Fastest, false);
```

Comment: What's .NET version?

Comment: It's actually .NET Core 3.1